# Как задеплоить Java Telegram-bot на railway

Tags: java, telegram-bot, github, jar, hosting

Я создал [телеграмм-бота](https://github.com/fakesib/tg-bot), и хотелось бы, чтобы он размещался на сервере. Я сделал следующее:

1. Нашёл сервис `railway`;
2. Закинул репозиторий с `gitHub`;
3. Ввёл стартовую команду(`java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*jar`);
4. Создал `jar`-файл класса `Main`;

Но вылезает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0.
```

Comment: Как минимум следует предоставить текст сообщения об ошибке, если вы хотите, чтобы кто-то начал рассматривать вашу проблему.  Постарайтесь также создать [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Смог сам разобраться спустя несколько дней проб и ошибок. Ошибка была в том, что я не закинул `jar`-файл в пакет `target`, и у меня стояла другая версия `java`. Ниже я сделал небольшую инструкцию по деплое тг-бота на `railway`. Нужно:

1. Создать `jar`-файл главного класса, закинуть в пакет `target`.
2. Поменять версию `java` на `17`.
3. Прописать в поле `Start Command`: `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*jar`.
4. И запустить